# Is there any way to use the xscreensaver gltext to monitor system information?

Tags: linux, x-windows, monitoring, screensaver

I am trying to get the X screensaver gltext to monitor my system temp and maybe some other stats. Writing a script that puts together the stats periodically is no problem, but the main thing I'm running into is that gltext doesn't refresh - whatever text I feed it stays there.

So, for example, I run this command:

```
$ /usr/lib/xscreensaver/gltext -text "`cat /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature`"
```

and get a gltext window showing:

```
temperature:             60 C
```

I can manipulate it and format it as necessary, but as my CPU heats up and cools down, it doesn't update, even if I include time variables that do.

I have a script that feeds gltext the time as the first line and the temp as the second line - and although the time updates continuously as the time changes, the temperature value remains the same as whenever the screensaver started.

Is it possible to do what I want, which is change the text every 60 seconds if the temperature changes?

Comment: Can you post the part of your script you refer to ("I have a script that feeds gltext the time as the first line and the temp as the second line")?

Comment: Never mind, I found out how it works, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. gltext has a `-program` flag that allows you to feed any script into it, and it updates every 5 seconds. `strftime` escape codes aren't processed normally, so any script run by the `-program` flag needs to have a way to output time.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that. You learn something every day.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation on gltext, it says:

> Displays a few lines of text spinning
>   around in a solid 3D font. The text
>   can use strftime() escape codes to
>   display the current date and time

This leads me to believe that the text sent into gltext is given to the function strftime and because of this, the time variables (escape codes)  will be dynamically updated. There is no evidence of some similar functionality for arbitrary information, or program execution, and therefore I'll have to say that it is not possible to do what you want to do.

In your specific case, when you run `` gltext -text "`cat /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature`" ``, your command is run once, and the resulting output is converted to an argument that is sent at startup to gltext, which will not know anything about what command once produced it.